# HP BladeSystem c3000 Enclosure : Ilo : Python : get_asset_tag() Not working

Tags: python, hp, hp-proliant, ilo, blade-server

I try to connect to a HP Blade Server (HP BladeSystem c3000 Enclosure ) using Python's HP-ILO module.

```
obj=hpilo.Ilo('172.8.2.29', login='Administrator', password='<redacted>', timeout=60, port=443, protocol=None, delayed=False)
```

Created a HP-ILO object using python library and try to get the asset tag details, i got the below error.

> hpilo.IloError: Remote returned bogus data, maybe it's not an iLO

Python API : https://pythonhosted.org/python-hpilo/ilo.html

I can connect the server via browser and ssh client too, but i couldn't connect the server via RIBCL scripts or using python.

Comment: Good thing the maintainer of the module frequents this site. I'll ask him to comment.

Answer (score 8):

This Python module is likely meant to work with the individual and standalone server ILO interfaces.

It is probably not intended for use with C7000 and C3000 blade enclosure Onboard Administrator modules.

Comment: As the author of that module, I can verify that this answer is correct :)

Answer (score 4):

The python-hpilo module can only speak to iLO interfaces, either using hponcfg to talk to the local iLO, or via the network. It cannot use the chassis onboard administrator, as it does not expose the same XML interface.